# Python: How to remove symbol in dict?

Tags: python, json, xml, response

I get a xml response which is in bytes and parsed by xmltodict as shown below. Since I need to further use the response, I want to eliminate all the '@' in the key. I have tried two way to remove the sign but still not working. Are there any method to remove sign in dict?

```
XML response (resp.text): {'HOLDING_QUERY_RESPONSE': OrderedDict([('@LOGIN_ID', '011'), ('@CLIENT_ID', '011'), ('@CHANNEL', 'MB'), ('@SESSION_KEY', '111'), ('RESULT', OrderedDict([('@STATUS', 'OK'), ('BUYING_POWER', '98’),( 'USD_BUYING_POWER', '12'), ('AVAILABLE_MKT_VAL', '110'), ('CASH_HOLDING', OrderedDict([('LINEITEM', [OrderedDict([('@CURRENCY_CODE', 'USD'), ('@AVAILABLE_BAL', '-233'), ('@CASH_BALANCE', '0.00'), ('@CASH_ON_HOLD', '0.00'), ('@UNSETTLED_CASH', '0.00'), ('@ACCRUED_INTEREST', '0.00'), ('@BUY_SOLD_CONSIDERATION', '-233'), ('@EX_RATE', '1'), ('@AVAILABLE_VAL', '6'), ('@AMT', '0.00'), ('@DUE_AMT', '0.00')]),…….)])])]))]))])}
```

First tried method. The error is dict object has no attribute 'iteritems()'. If I remove the '.iteritem()', it will show Value Error: too many value to unpack.

```
info = {key.replace('@',''): item for key, item in xmltodict.parse(resp.text).iteritems()}
print(info)
```

Second tried method is changed it to string first and then translate it back to dict. But, still it seems the dict has not translate to string by json.dumps.

```
info = json.dumps(resp.text)
info.replace('@','')
to_dict = json.loads(info)
print(to_dict)
```

Comment: Try `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()`. You might be using Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Austin. I tried this before, but still showing dict object has no item() attribute.

Comment: it's `items()`.

Comment: `info.replace('@','')` returns a new string, which you're ignoring, by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
info = {key.replace('@',''): item for key, item in xmltodict.parse(resp.text).items()}
print(info)
```

As mentioned in the comments, `xmltodict.parse` returns a dictionary, and in your case, you might be working with Python 3, so use the `.items()` attribute to access the dictionary.

As an example:

```
d = ('@CASH', '0.00'), ('@INTEREST', '0.00'), ('@BUY', '-233'), ('@RATE', '1.000000'), ('@AVAILABLE', '6,228'), ('@AMT', '0.00')
info = {key.replace('@',''): item for key, item in d}

print(info)
>>
{'CASH': '0.00', 'INTEREST': '0.00', 'BUY': '-233', 'RATE': '1.000000', 'AVAILABLE': '6,228', 'AMT': '0.00'}
```

**Updated question soution**

Similarly, if it is a nested dictionary, you have to access the key you want to replace `@` in its values, from your updated example, you should be able to access the nested dictionary with `xmltodict.parse(resp.text)['HOLDING_QUERY_RESPONSE']`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

#based on your updated data structure
d = OrderedDict([('@CASH', '0.00'), ('@INTEREST', '0.00'), ('@BUY', '-233'), ('@RATE', '1.000000'), ('@AVAILABLE', '6,228'), ('@AMT', '0.00')])
xml_response = {}
xml_response['HOLDING_QUERY_RESPONSE'] = d

xml_response
{'HOLDING_QUERY_RESPONSE': OrderedDict([('@CASH', '0.00'),
              ('@INTEREST', '0.00'),
              ('@BUY', '-233'),
              ('@RATE', '1.000000'),
              ('@AVAILABLE', '6,228'),
              ('@AMT', '0.00')])}

info = {key.replace('@',''):value for key, value in xml_response['HOLDING_QUERY_RESPONSE'].items()}
print(info)
```

Comment: Thanks, now the error is gone, but I found that the @ sign is still there.

Comment: I added an example, it should work and its pretty straightforward. Are you accessing the right variables?

Comment: I also edited the resp.text. Actually the dict is like this and have many layer. Does it affect the result of simply using the above code?

Comment: @WILL this only works on the top level keys of the dictionary

Comment: I edited my answer based on the update, if any of the answers here solved your problem, kindly accept the best one as your answer.